# Group dates by midday instead of midnight

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataset that has multiple collections per day some days.  I want to create a field that I can use to bundle the 'days' up, but I want to split at midday instead of midnight.  Unfortunately, when I do the "midday split", the date value is coming through as an integer instead of a date value.

Some sample code:

```
library(tidyverse)
x <- as.POSIXct(Sys.time()) 

y <- as.tibble(x)

#midnights comes through correctly as a date
y %>%
  mutate(midnights=as.Date(value)) 

#middays comes through as an integer instead of a date
y %>%
  mutate(middays=ifelse(as.numeric(format(value,"%H")) >= 12,
                        as.Date(value),
                        as.Date(value)-1))
```

What should I be doing differently?

Comment: I don't know what you could do to fix up your code - but what happens if you add/subtract 12 hours to your days before you try to group them, then remove/add the 12 hours back in before you use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifelse` returns a numeric because it strips class information. Just wrap the whole thing in another `as.Date()`:

```
y %>%
  mutate(middays=as.Date(ifelse(as.numeric(format(value,"%H")) >= 12,
                        as.Date(value),
                        as.Date(value)-1),origin="1970-01-01"))
```

or use the `if_else` in `dplyr` which sorts this out

```
y %>%
  mutate(middays=if_else(as.numeric(format(value,"%H")) >= 12,
                        as.Date(value),
                        as.Date(value)-1))

## A tibble: 1 × 2
#                value    middays
#               <dttm>     <date>
#1 2017-09-21 08:28:05 2017-09-19
```

Comment: if_else seems the easiest solution out of the options :)

Answer (score 2):

One trick you can use is to convert `x` to seconds since epoch, by calling `as.numeric(x)`. Then to get the number of days since epoch, it's just `as.numeric(x) %/% 86400` (since there are 86400 seconds in a day). So, you can use this value to split by day (i.e. splitting at midnight). If you want to 'shift' this by 12 hours, all you need to do is shift `x` by 12 hours, i.e. run `as.numeric(dates + 12 * 3600) %/% 86400`.

For example

```
dates <- structure(c(1505771227.18457, 1505814427.18457, 1505857627.18457, 
         1505900827.18457, 1505944027.18457, 1505987227.18457, 
         1506030427.18457), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
#[1] "2017-09-18 22:47:07 BST" "2017-09-19 10:47:07 BST" "2017-09-19 22:47:07 BST" "2017-09-20 10:47:07 BST"
#[5] "2017-09-20 22:47:07 BST" "2017-09-21 10:47:07 BST" "2017-09-21 22:47:07 BST"

as.numeric(dates) %/% 86400 # use this to group by day (split at midnight)
#[1] 17427 17428 17428 17429 17429 17430 17430

as.numeric(dates + 12 * 3600) %/% 86400 # use this to split at noon
#[1] 17428 17428 17429 17429 17430 17430 17431
```

Alternatively, if you want to use `lubridate` you can play the same trick, i.e. calculate `lubridate::floor_date(dates + lubridate::hours(12), 'day')` which shifts the date by 12 hours and then finds the day, and group by that.